# Javascript image manipulation - coloring mask ideas and solutions

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, webgl, image-manipulation

I have question related with coloring image (mask) in Javascript. I am looking for technologies stack, libraries, ideas which help mi with my issue. I plan to write JS app which allow user to color part of image, I mean that if you have fence image, you could color the wood. I will have image and mask (transparent image with black places where color should be placed). Application should give possibility to change saturation of placed color on image (te texture should be more or less visible depend on color category) and adding additional texture on mask where color will be placed for e.g. changin wood grain.

Can you tell me which approach will be better? Should I use third-party library (e.g. WebGL like pixi or three js) or simply canvas and iterating though pixels and manipulate them, e.g. making average color by taking R and G and B value of image pixel and destination color (but I see problems with putting textures and saturation). Or maybe you will have some other ideas? 
I don't know that I described problem clearly. If you have some questions, please ask and I answer it. 
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a job for the HTML5 `Canvas.context.clip()` method to me.  [More info @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip).

Comment: What you need is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation This will provide the mask, and the variouse operations to change hue, saturation, etc. Just layer each FX on top of the canvase with `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = ?; ctx.drawImage(mask...` or a color or texture. The only limitations are imagination.